# ios: when I do a pagination in UITableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, listview

I want to do pagination in UITableView.

For example,

If I show you 20 article

1. Do I need to send a 20 times HTTP Request ?

=> return 1 data row

2. DO I need to send a 1 times HTTP Request()

=> return 20 data row

Comment: prob option 2, but this is entirely up to you and what works best for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little bit tricky. Probably you don't know about 'lazy loading'. This is the choice in this regard. Before saying the reasons, lets see the problems of two options you provided.

Consider 2nd option: if you want 20 articles at a times. Then you have to wait to all data of these 20 articles. If once all 20 articles downloaded successfully then only user can see a article. Otherwise, user have to wait until it download. Which makes a user boring.

Consider the 1st option: it will reduces the 2nd option problem. But it still remains other problem.if user scrolling the table cell to see a specific article then the table cell will stack because in background thread downloading continue so UI will hang.

3rd option:download 1 by 1 items with lazy loading(like Facebook ). If data comes user will see article otherwise cell will empty but UI will never stack/ hang.

Answer (score 0):

#### You can use these method of tableview delegate

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView

- When your scroll reach at 20 you can call web service, these process done again when reach 40 etc.